# 3D model scn file does not rotate or scale in AR kit

Tags: xcode, arkit, scnscene

I started a new Xcode project with the ARKit template and simply replaced the "ship.scn" with my "test.scn" filename asset. The object is about 16.5mm wide and 4.8mm tall. The ship worked fine of course, but my test object that reads "test" does not rotate as I move around it, or scale when I move towards or away from it, yet it does track in one location.

I compared the ship and test attribute panels, and I can't find anything that is different about them, except that the ship is textured and my test text is not. What is inherently special about scn objects that would make them behave correctly in ARKit besides their size? I've read through the documentation about anchoring, but it seems like I wouldn't have to do this in code if it's already a scn object.

In case anyone wants to test the file I'm using in the ARKit template to see how it's behaving, the file is here: https://ufile.io/ey49t

Answer (score 0):

I’m answering the question because I think it could help others that are making a similar mistake, but it can be closed if it doesn’t make sense.

The problem is that the size was much too large where I could not see scaling or rotation no matter how much I moved around the room. Compare the scaled size in the last attribute panel on the ship model - not its actual size. Then get the size of your own model scaled down enough so that it is actually resonable.

[image: scale in node inspector]
[image: actual size shown in scene inspector]